# the simplest way to store/restore queue of downloads

Tags: java, android

I need to store queue of downloads and then restore it:

- each downlaod should be restored from the already downloaded position
- storage should be persistent (switch off->switch on device)

What is the simplest way to do it (any techniques, approaches)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What is the simplest way to do it (any techniques, approaches)?

Square's [Tape](http://square.github.io/tape/) is designed to implement a persistent queue, which they use for queuing HTTP operations. The download work you will have to write yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Use the built-in [DownloadManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DownloadManager.html) class.

> The download manager is a system service that handles long-running HTTP downloads. Clients may request that a URI be downloaded to a particular destination file. The download manager will conduct the download in the background, taking care of HTTP interactions and retrying downloads after failures or across connectivity changes and system reboots. Instances of this class should be obtained through getSystemService(String) by passing DOWNLOAD_SERVICE. Apps that request downloads through this API should register a broadcast receiver for ACTION_NOTIFICATION_CLICKED to appropriately handle when the user clicks on a running download in a notification or from the downloads UI. Note that the application must have the INTERNET permission to use this class.

Comment: Didn't know that was a requirement. :)

Comment: @barn.gumbl: Actually, SSL is fixed. Added in 4.0, IIRC.

Comment: I use Android 2.3 and as I remember it's not easy to move it to custom code